# Uikit switcher component & current window hash

Tags: javascript, css

Uikit have Switcher component - https://getuikit.com/docs/switcher.

I need the selected tab added to the address bar and not reset when the page reloads. for example

```
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill" uk-switcher>
<li><a href="#tab1">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">Item</a></li>
```

```
<ul class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
<li>Hello!</li>
<li>Hello again!</li>
<li>Bazinga!</li>
```

Please help with the solution of this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this piece of code before closing body tag. This is one idea, you may develop on this

```
// Replace .uk-subnav with your switcher element
const switcherEl = document.querySelector('.uk-subnav');
const anchors = switcherEl.querySelectorAll('li > a');
const switcher = UIkit.switcher(switcherEl);

// Show content corresponds to location hash
let active = 0;
while(anchors[active]) {  
  if(anchors[active].hash === window.location.hash) {
    switcher.show(active);    
    break;
  }
  active++;
}

// Update location hash in address bar.
switcherEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => window.location.hash = event.target.hash.substr(1));
```

Comment: Thats what i need! Thank you so much!